# Using accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility

I want to create an android app which will "scan" other applications'layouts and find out if there are buttons etc.
Some apps, like whatsapp, doesn't allow third parts to move into the app, so I though that using accessibility could be the solution.
Now the problem is that I've never used Accessibility, so can someone of you can please show me how to "scan" an app's layout to find buttons?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't see why this would be closed.  It seems to me like anyone voting to close this misunderstands the question.  Android Accessibility Service boilerplate code is a great question!  I will work on an answer.  I've been meaning to post a github repo with some A11y Service boilerplate.  Give me 24 hours!  ANd don't close this question, just because you don't understand it!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an Accessibility Service.  Configuring an accessibility service is somewhat complicated.  I have set up a repository of accessibility boilerplate code that sets up an AccessibilityService that logs the node heirarchy to LogCat, and has the default project settings activity set up as it's settings activity.  Here are some of the highlights, as I dislike just posting github repos as answers.  Note that I use a lot of my own libraries.  CLog is a logging library and AndroidAccessibilityUtils wraps node infos with some common utility functions.  You can find references to the dependencies in the build.gradle file on the github repo at the bottom.  Here are some code highlights.

Your manifest.xml file is going to be significantly different from an Activity, and should contain an entry like this in your Application element:

```
<application .... >
    ...
    <service
        android:name="com.moba11y.basicaccessibilityservice.BasicAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/service_config" />

    </service>
    ...
</application>
```

First you need to create a subclass of Accessibility Service:

```
public class BasicAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    static {
        CLog.initialize(BasicAccessibilityService.class.getSimpleName(), BuildConfig.DEBUG);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        CLog.d(event.toString());

        switch (event.getEventType()) {
            //On Gesture events print out the entire view heirarchy!
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_GESTURE_DETECTION_START:
                CLog.d(A11yNodeInfo.wrap(getRootInActiveWindow()).toViewHeirarchy());

            default: {
                //If the event has a source, let's print it out separately.
                if (event.getSource() != null) {
                    CLog.d(A11yNodeInfo.wrap(event.getSource()).toViewHeirarchy());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        CLog.e("Service Interrupted: Have never actually had this happen.");
    }
}
```

That is the bulk of the highlights.  You also should have a "service_config" XML with properties, as is referenced in the changes to the Manifest XML file.  More details, and a reasonable starer point can be found in the open source repo on GitHub.

https://github.com/chriscm2006/Android-Accessibility-Service-Boilerplate